# I cannot get rid of "component" part of SEF URL in Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I have created 5 menu ítems that point to the same URL, that is index.php?option=com_hum&view=comunidad.

All of them are loaded with http://doamin/alias.html. That is good, but when I show the menu module in the page.

On the other hand, I have an icon that I need to place a link to the first of that menu items, so I added a link to JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_hum&view=comunidad')

When I load the page, the actual link for the icon is http://domain/component/hum/comunidad.html. The correct should be http://domain/muro.html, which is the first menu item with "index.php?option=com_hum&view=comunidad" link.

any help?

This is Joomla 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

first of all get rid of J3.3.3 and update we're on 3.7.1 now! and routing was improved;
Second, change your manual link adding the Itemid that Joomla uses to discriminate between menu items; so your url should look like:

```
"_index.php?option=com_hum&view=comunidad&Itemid=343"
```

You can find the Itemid easily simply open the menu manager it is the number on the right (column ID)

[image: menu manager].

And to make sure the rest of the url is correct, Joomla writes the url right under the menu item name:

[image: menu item edit]

Comment: How to get Itemid without hardcoding it? By mean of a method call or something using item alias?

Comment: I have hardcoded Itemid but now the URL is: http://domain/muro/comunidad.html. The alias of the item is "muro", so the url should be just http://domain/muro.html, and in fact, when I use any of those URL's the same page is loaded which is bad from SEO and analytics point of view.

Comment: You only need to hardcode Itemid if there are multiple menu items with the same non-sef url; otherwise Joomla will figure it out by itself.  Is "comunidad" the template or layout name? where does it come from? if you add it to the original non-sef url does it work?

Comment: Comunidad is a view of my custom component. Thar view has a setting that allows to decide which layout to load. All of those menu items has the same view but different layout setting. But hardcoding it, it worked, but, is it possible to get the itemid by mean of the item alias?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to load it from the #__menu table, JRoute only has the default "_" method